# How to remove <p> tags from tinymce in YII2

Tags: php, yii2, tinymce

p tags are being saved in my database, can someone tell me how to remove them pls?

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'comments')->widget(TinyMce::className(), [
    'options' => ['rows' => 6],
    'language' => 'en',
    'clientOptions' => [
        'plugins' => [
            "advlist autolink lists link charmap print preview anchor",
            "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
            "insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste",
        ],
        'toolbar' => "undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image"
    ]
]);?>
```

The above is my code. Thanks

Comment: TinyMCE is an HTML editor so it will give you HTML as an outcome.  If you don't need HTML for your project why not just use a simple textarea?

Comment: To answer your query, it would be useful to know what your use case is. Looking at the plugins listed in your config, it appears you want to support many other HTML elements (links, lists, tables, etc), but why not paragraphs? What do you want them replaced with? Do you want no new lines?